# How to find the image of the inverse Laplace operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ supremum norm. $\Delta: \mathcal{D}(\Delta)\subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)\to C_0(\mathbb{R}^2),$ where $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^2):\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(x,y)=0,|z|^2=x^2+y^2\}.$ How do we find the space $\mathcal{D}(\Delta)=\Delta^{-1}(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$?

Comment: Here's a thought. $C_0$ is the image of $L^1$ under the Fourier transform. Perhaps there's an argument along these lines since the Fourier transform plays nicely with derivatives?

Comment: @CameronWilliams The Fourier transform isn't surjective from $L^1 \to C_0$ !

Comment: @Brozovic oh shoot. You're right. But it is dense, though I suspect that isn't enough.

Comment: Is it possible to find the image of inverse Laplace operator?

Comment: $C^2_0(\mathbb{R})$ should be in the $\mathcal{D}(\Delta).$ But I do not know how to enlarge it?